# collision of Circles with different sizes

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, game-physics

I am facing issue with circles collision of two different sizes but i don't understand what exactly i am doing wrong.

Right now for referece i post code of same circle sizes, you can run and test its working fine.

but when you change size of circle2 from css (440px) collision will not work anymore.

Looking forward for help if someone can help me to solve this issue.

```js
const circle1 = document.getElementById('circle1');
const circle2 = document.getElementById('circle2');
const square1 = document.getElementById('square1');

const circle1_w = circle1.offsetWidth / 2;
const circle1_h = circle1.offsetHeight / 2;

const circle2_w = circle2.offsetWidth / 2;
const circle2_h = circle2.offsetHeight / 2;

const square_w = square1.offsetWidth / 2;
const square_h = square1.offsetHeight / 2;

document.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  circle2.style.left = e.clientX - circle2_w + 'px';
  circle2.style.top = e.clientY - circle2_h + 'px';
  square1.style.left = e.clientX - square_w + 'px';
  square1.style.top = e.clientY - square_h + 'px';
  collideCircle();
});

console.log(circle2);

function collideCircle() {
  var circle1Bounding = circle1.getBoundingClientRect();
  var circle2Bounding = circle2.getBoundingClientRect();

  const circle1_x = circle1Bounding.x;
  const circle1_y = circle1Bounding.y;

  const circle2_x = circle2Bounding.x;
  const circle2_y = circle2Bounding.y;

  /* first we get the x and y distance between the two circles. */
  let distance_x = circle1_x - circle2_x;
  let distance_y = circle1_y - circle2_y;

  /* Then we get the sum of their radii. */
  let radii_sum = circle1_w + circle2_w;

  let sideA = Math.abs(circle1_y - circle2_y);
  let sideB = Math.abs(circle1_x - circle2_x);
  let distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(sideA, 2) + Math.pow(sideB, 2));
  if (distance <= (circle1Bounding.width + circle2Bounding.width) / 2) {
    circle1.innerHTML = 'Collision occured';
    circle1.style.backgroundColor = 'pink';
  } else {
    circle1.innerHTML = '';
    circle1.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#circle1 {
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50vw;
  top: 50vh;
  background-color: rgb(255, 233, 36);
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#circle2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 80, 80);
  font-size: 1.5em;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#square1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="circle1"></div>
<div id="circle2"></div>
<div id="square1"></div>
```

Any idea what exactly i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For circle collision detection, you want to measure the distance between their *center* points and see if that distance is less than the sum of the circles' radii.

`getBoundingClientRect` returns a rectangle whose `X, Y` values denote the upper-left corner. Your mistake was continuing the calculations with that value.

I updated your code so `circle1_x` (and y, for circle 1 and 2) account for the circle's center position relative to the bounding rectangle's corner.

Also, assuming they are *circles* and not ovals, you can grab the width and ignore the height, to determine the *radius*. I updated your code to derive `circle1_r` and `circle2_r` instead of h/w for each circle respectively.

```js
const circle1 = document.getElementById('circle1');
const circle2 = document.getElementById('circle2');
const square1 = document.getElementById('square1');

// assume circle H=W and just get its radius
const circle1_r = circle1.offsetWidth / 2;
const circle2_r = circle2.offsetWidth / 2;

const square_w = square1.offsetWidth / 2;
const square_h = square1.offsetHeight / 2;

document.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  circle2.style.left = e.clientX - circle2_r + 'px';
  circle2.style.top = e.clientY - circle2_r + 'px';
  square1.style.left = e.clientX - square_w + 'px';
  square1.style.top = e.clientY - square_h + 'px';
  collideCircle();
});

console.log(circle2);

function collideCircle() {
  var circle1Bounding = circle1.getBoundingClientRect();
  var circle2Bounding = circle2.getBoundingClientRect();

  // get *center* position for circles
  const circle1_x = circle1Bounding.x + circle1_r;
  const circle1_y = circle1Bounding.y + circle1_r;

  const circle2_x = circle2Bounding.x + circle2_r;
  const circle2_y = circle2Bounding.y + circle2_r;

  /* first we get the x and y distance between the two circles. */
  let distance_x = circle1_x - circle2_x;
  let distance_y = circle1_y - circle2_y;

  /* Then we get the sum of their radii. */
  let radii_sum = circle1_r + circle2_r;

  let sideA = Math.abs(circle1_y - circle2_y);
  let sideB = Math.abs(circle1_x - circle2_x);
  let distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(sideA, 2) + Math.pow(sideB, 2));
  if (distance <= (circle1Bounding.width + circle2Bounding.width) / 2) {
    circle1.innerHTML = 'Collision occured';
    circle1.style.backgroundColor = 'pink';
  } else {
    circle1.innerHTML = '';
    circle1.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#circle1 {
  width: 210px;
  height: 210px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50vw;
  top: 50vh;
  background-color: rgb(255, 233, 36);
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#circle2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 80, 80);
  font-size: 1.5em;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#square1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="circle1"></div>
<div id="circle2"></div>
<div id="square1"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your time and effort, i have confusion will we handle same algo to manage multiple circle collision?
like for loop etc or in that case we have some better code?

Comment: If there are multiple circles, you will need to check for each circle if that circle intersects with any of the other circles. But you can use the same logic for each individual check i.e. determine if the distance between their centers is less than the sum of their radii. There are possible optimizations to make, but they are beyond the scope of a Q&A site; I suggest googling "collision detection" as it is a fairly deep field.